# Installing/Using a new class in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: document-classes, ubuntu

This question will probably have great intersection with other questions, but I would be grateful for any help or references to relevant answers.

I am quite a novice at Ubuntu, I use 12.04.1 LTS. I want to install/use a class available online (called "asl.cls", available here: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~asl/).

I made a new folder named "asl" (at the path: /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/asl) and then copied the class asl.cls inside that folder (was this right?). I then ran (sudo) texhash to update, but it did not work.

As an alternative solution, I also tried to keep the class asl.cls inside the same folder with the working .tex file which I am currently trying to write. Still not working.

In fact, upon compilation of the working .tex file (with documentclass "asl"), Kile opens a new tab with a file called "amsopn.sty", the cursor stops at some point in the middle of that file, and the compilation window is full of errors. Apparently, looking at the list of errors, there seem to be conflicts between operators or other commands already defined in the file "amsopn.sty" (and also in the file "amsmath.sty", indeed, much more conflicts with "amsmath", which nevertheless does not open in another tab). I have never seen such a thing happen before, and I have been using tex for some time now.

Let me mention that my working .tex file is error free otherwise. I.e., if I just replace "asl" by regular "amsart" in the documentclass, everything compiles smoothly.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: Try to comment your ams packages and let the class load them. *The packages amsfonts.sty and amssymb.sty are loaded if they exist, otherwise a warning is given that ams fonts are not available and compilation does not stop until some amsfont symbol is required.*

Comment: You should **never** manually install packages into the tree managed by your package manager any more than you should manually install programmes into `/usr/bin`. Instead, use either the local texmf tree or, easiest, your personal texmf tree. For example, `~/texmf/tex/latex/asl/asl.cls`. You do not need to run `texhash` or `maketexlsr` in that case - all you need do is drop the files in an appropriate spot.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).  However, note that this class claims to 'know' `amsopn version 1.2b [1996/10/28]
and cannot load amsopn.`  This not promising since my system has 'Version 2.01, 1999/12/14'; it is likely you do too.  I've no doubt a solution can be found, but not until we see a useful example to test.